# Copiar uma coluna de uma determinada tabela para outra coluna de outra tabela

Tags: sql, oracle

Estou tentando fazer o update abaixo, só que estou tendo dificuldade. Desde já fico grato pela ajuda!!

```
UPDATE pctabpr set pctabpr.ptabela = (SELECT ptabela 
                                      FROM pcembalagem 
                                      WHERE pcembalagem.codprod = pctabpr.codprod);
```

O que está errado?

Comment: E qual é sua dificuldade?

Comment: não sei se meu update está correto está dando erro na hora de processar

Comment: Qual erro? Acrescente mais detalhes a respeito do problema.

Comment: Você precisa dar informações mais precisas sobre qual erro, a mensagem, o erro ORA-XXXX, etc. De qualquer forma, olhando seu update, se o subselect trouxer mais de um valor vai dar erro, já verificou isso? Além disso, você omitiu no seu exemplo ou seu `UPDATE` está sem `WHERE`?

Comment: Para que este UPDATE funcione o SELECT em questão precisa retorna uma e somente uma linha, pode ser este o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Como o Motta disse no comentário, provavelmente está vindo mais de 1 registro na sua subquery.

Acredito que com `JOIN` você resolveria esse caso:

```
UPDATE pctabpr 
SET ptabela = E.ptabela
FROM pctabpr A
INNER JOIN pcembalagem E ON E.codprod = A.codprod
```